# angularjs $q run multiple promises on sequence

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I was working on AngularJS 1.5.3 project, and I'm having trouble with chaining promises.

I have a function that looks like that;

```
this.login = function(u,p){ var promise=$auth.login(u,p).then(...); return promise;}
this.tests = [
    ['Im LoginController, i let users login'],
    ['I have logs attr, to bind current state to view',null,function(){return !!angular.isArray(self.log)}],
    ['I have $auth attr, that expse the $auth service',function(){return !!(self.$auth===$auth)}],
    ['I can get tokens from server',null,function(){return self.login({u:1,pass:1234})},function(){return !!($auth.currentUser.id === 1 && $auth.currentUser.hasValidToken()===true)}
];
```

I think you can see what I'm trying here...

So the array is composed of

```
[
    0 => string
    1 => a function that return promise
    2 => a function that confirms that the previous function effects took place
]
```

I wanted to create a directive to autotest controllers presenting visual aids- anyhow-,

What I need is to loop the array and execute them in order and return true/false for [1,2];

My first attempt was directly into Angular1 template using `ngRepeat`

```
<ul>
  <li ng-if="$last ng-repeat="test in tests">{{test[0]}} :: {{test[1]() && test[2]()}}</li>
</ul>
```

Failed very bad, because of course they don't execute in order. So I realized I need to wrap them in promises ?

Comment: If `tests` is an array then it will iterate them in what ever order the array is in, if its iterating an object thats when the order can't be guaranteed. However with an ng-repeat they will all execute pretty much at the same time. Have a look at [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) if thats desired as this will do it all in code rather than relying on angular bindings. Would make it easier to test.

Comment: @ste2425 array contain array, and mixed values 'string,function' $q.all can handle all that ?

Answer (score 1):

You could execute all tests in a controller before rendering them with `ng-repeat` and then using [`$q.all()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) make sure they all are resolved while storing their results in a separate variable. In particular something along these lines:

```
var testCases = [
    ['Im LoginController, i let users login'],
    ['I have logs...', null, function(){return !!angular.isArray(self.log)}],
];

var promises = [];

scope.testResults = [];
scope.testsExecuted = false;

for (var i = 0; i < this.pendingScenarios.length; i++) {
    var testCase = this.testCases[i];
    if (testCase[1]) {
        var result = $.when(testCase[1]());
        result.then(function(result) {
            testResults[i] = result;
        });
        promises.push(result);
    }
    // ...
}

$q.all(promises).then(function() {
    $scope.testsExecuted = true;
});
```

I didn't test the code but I think you get the idea. If the test returns a Promise you put it into an array and at the end make sure they all are resolved while `result.then()` storing its result.

Comment: You could use `$q.when` to wrap non promises in a promise then you don't need to check yourself but `$q.all` will also do this. Then you can pass an array of promises into `$q.all` and let it combine the results for you. `$q.all` will resolve with all the resolved values from the array of promises. So you don't need to do that yourself either. https://jsfiddle.net/29n63c1s/

Comment: @ste2425 thanks for the fiddle, yet all functions return null when wrapped in $q.when() any idea why ? var promises = [$q.when(function(){ return 10; }), $q.when(function(){return true}) , .. or any function will always return null, even if it returns a $q.when